# Calculate Row Decile/Quantile by Column Dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains price returns by row displayed in columns that are each a different year.  I'd like to either insert a new column after each existing column with a decile or quantile value for the value in the row of the annual return column to the left.

I can add a ranking for each row's value by column by creating a new data frame using the following:

```
test <- yearRetsMSA2 %>%
  mutate(across(c(cnam_year2[1]:cnam_year2[length(cnam_year2)]), rank))
```

Where yearRetsMSA2 is the table with column names by year and row names by territory.  cnam_year2 is a character vector with the column names for the data frame yearRetsMSA2.  There are some NA values in certain spots of each column vector, but the below script is not working:

```
test2 <- yearRetsMSA2 %>%
mutate(across(c(cnam_year2[1]:cnam_year2[length(cnam_year2)]), quantile(na.omit())))

structure(list(`1995 Return` = c(0.0151000000000001, 0.0463), 
    `1996 Return` = c(0.0361540734902965, 0.050750262830928), 
    `1997 Return` = c(0.036223616657159, 0.049208659268692), 
    `1998 Return` = c(0.0213781080833104, 0.0508019072388384), 
    `1999 Return` = c(0.0369205892921309, 0.023265407144625), 
    `2000 Return` = c(0.0177596811920644, 0.042892848504394), 
    `2001 Return` = c(0.0474123255022132, 0.0538074990336297), 
    `2002 Return` = c(0.0282811865095489, 0.0258968527620864), 
    `2003 Return` = c(-0.00505808899075322, 0.0240989702517163
    ), `2004 Return` = c(0.0660100087377868, 0.0309335940227635
    ), `2005 Return` = c(0.0777943368107303, 0.0308859387699811
    ), `2006 Return` = c(0.0893252212389382, -0.00683311432325884
    ), `2007 Return` = c(0.0338283828382837, -0.0302990209050013
    ), `2008 Return` = c(0.0355454601264658, -0.0375221721926593
    ), `2009 Return` = c(0.00361631491581682, -0.0233909838389567
    ), `2010 Return` = c(0.000472561876070809, -0.0121933517201336
    ), `2011 Return` = c(-0.0144653716714885, -0.0449669360764144
    ), `2012 Return` = c(0.0181524083393243, -0.012925065394676
    ), `2013 Return` = c(0.0614886731391586, 0.0127825409197193
    ), `2014 Return` = c(0.0437361419068736, 0.0333230721871633
    ), `2015 Return` = c(0.0364331616124065, 0.0430475906755046
    ), `2016 Return` = c(0.0472457084294133, 0.0165655123170296
    ), `2017 Return` = c(0.0218231638694526, 0.0523986794970852
    ), `2018 Return` = c(0.0755159699276924, 0.036975238603751
    ), `2019 Return` = c(0.0231967943009797, 0.0610800025744997
    ), `2020 Return` = c(0.0486488838605805, 0.0724857454810142
    ), `2021 Return` = c(0.196107722312129, 0.140093886092416
    ), `2022 Return` = c(0.069071986123157, 0.119059430499058
    )), row.names = c("Abilene, TX", "Akron, OH"), class = "data.frame")
```

Additionally, with the solution here that inserts a new column next to each column solving the quantile issue, how would you modify the current script to similarly insert a column with the ranking next to each existing column?  The final table's format would retain the excellent structure included with the quantile/decile script.

Help solving this is much appreciated!

Comment: please share at least a subset of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a generic approach with {dplyr}:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
                .fns = ~ findInterval(.x, quantile(.x, c(.2 * 1:5), na.rm = TRUE)),
                .names = "{.col}_quantile")) %>%
  select(names(.) %>% sort)
```

Anyhow, the **[tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#pivoting)verse** way would be to `pivot_longer` your dataframe, group it, apply the desired `mutate`ions and (if need be) `pivot_wider` it to wide format again.

Example (`df` being your sample dataframe):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_long <- 
  df |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column('state') |>
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with('Return'),
               names_to = 'year',
               values_to = 'return'
               ) |>
  mutate(year = gsub(' .*', '', year)) |>
  group_by(state) |>
  mutate(quant = findInterval(return, quantile(return, 1:5 * .2, na.rm = TRUE))) |>
  ungroup()


df_long |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, 
              values_from = c('return', 'quant'),
              names_vary = 'slowest'
              )
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the following error with the na values: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `1995 Return_quantile`.
Caused by error in `quantile.default()`:
! missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I also need it to work row wise column by column listing the quantile by row value.

Comment: js80, please see edit

Comment: You got it!  Works well now! Thanks!

Comment: How would I format the initial rank script to insert the new columns with the rank next to the yearly return column the way you have with the quantile?